# Inheritance/namespacing in Ruby gem

Tags: ruby, inheritance, rubygems

I am working on a Ruby gem that faces off to a sports api. I do not fully understand classes/inheritance and am looking for some guidance.

The predicament is I have multiple sports, baseball, basketball etc. and they all have some similar overlap in resources, i.e. players, teams etc.

Currently I have it structured as follows:

```
module SportsApi
  module Mlb
    class Player
    end
  end
end
```

If I have the following, would my player class be overwritten or is it ok because it is wrapped inside of a module?

```
module SportsApi
  module Nfl
    class Player
    end
  end
end
```

Should I just have a player class that is common across all sports and then create separate MlbPlayer, NflPlayer classes that inherit from the generic player class? I feel like I kind of need a rails single table inheritance structure but now sure how I would reimplement that in this gem structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I have the following, would my player class be overwritten or is it ok because it is wrapped inside of a module?

No, your class won't be overwritten. Except if someone does it on purpose by accessing the `SportsApi::Mlb` namespace.

> Should I just have a player class that is common across all sports and then create separate MlbPlayer, NflPlayer classes that inherit from the generic player class?

The question is, what `MlbPlayer` & `NflPlayer` would need from `Player`? Would it need all of its functionality and would diverge a little from it or it would *share* some functionality with it?

Inheritance is considered not-so-good by many for a bunch of reasons, mostly because it fails to model the real world (where relationships are mostly "has-a" and not "is-a") so I'd suggest that you consider using *Composition*: http://rubysource.com/composition-inheritance/

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
module SportsApi
  # Common methods go here
end

class Player
  include SportsApi
  # Super class
end

class NFLPlayer < Player
  # Child class
end

class NBAPlayer < Player
  # Child class
end
```

Comment: Use `<` for inheritance, not `>`.